# for loop: commands start from begin every time

Tags: bash, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I have write the following bash script to check list of domains from `domain.list` and multiple directories from `dir.list`.

@ is the first domain, it first tries to find file at 
http://example.com
if success script finish and exit no problem.

if failed it go to check it at 
https://example.com
if ok , script finish and exit, 
if not 
check for it at 
`http://example.com/$list` of different directories.

If file found script finished and exit , if failed to find 
then go to check it at
`https://example.com/$list` of different directories

But the problem , when the first check failed and second check failed , it goes to third check , but it keep looping , at third command and 4th command, tell it find file or list of directories finished.

I want the script when reach the 3rd command to run it and check for it at list of directories tell the list finish and not to go for the 4th command tell it finished

As at my script it keep checking for single domain at multiple directories and every time to check a new directory it start the whole script from the bagain and run the 1st command and 2nd command again from the begin and I do not need that, big loss of time

Thanks

```
#!/bin/bash
dirs=(`cat dir.list`)
doms=( `cat domain.list`)
for dom in "${doms[@]}"
do
for dir in "${dirs[@]}"
do
target1="http://${dom}"
target2="https://${dom}"
target3="http://${dom}/${dir}"
target4="https://${dom}/${dir}"

if curl -s --insecure -m2 ${target1}/test.txt | grep "success" > /dev/null ;then
echo ${target1} >> dir.result
break
elif curl -s --insecure -m2 ${target2}/test.txt | grep "success"  > /dev/null;then
echo ${target2} >> dir.result
break
elif  curl -s --insecure -m2 ${target3}/test.txt | grep "success"  > /dev/null; then
echo ${target3} >> dir.result
break
elif  curl -s --insecure -m2 ${target4}/test.txt | grep "success" > /dev/null ; then
echo ${target4} >> dir.result
break
fi
done
done
```

Comment: maybe `break 2` would help

Comment: where to put it ?? at which part ??

Comment: The normal name for what follows the colon in `http://example.com:xyz` is 'port', not 'directory'.

Comment: iam sorry i was mistaken , as i copied the code from another code i wrote in past

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is sub-optimal; if you have a list of 5 'dir' values, you check 5 times whether `http://${domain}/test.txt` exists — but the chances are that if it didn't exist the first time, it doesn't exist on the other times either.

You use `dir` to indicate a sub-directory name, but your code uses `http://${dom}:${dir}` rather than the more normal `http://${dom}/${dir}`.  Technically, what follows the colon up to the first slash is a port number, not a directory.  I'm going to assume this is a typo and the colon should be replaced by a slash.

Generally, do not use the back-tick notation; use `$(…)` instead.  Avoid swathes of repeated code, too.

I think you can compress your script down to something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
dirs=( $(cat dir.list) )
file=test.txt

fetch_file()
{
    if curl -s --insecure -m2 "${1:?}/${file}" | grep "success" > /dev/null
    then
        echo "${1}"
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

for dom in $(cat domain.list)
do
    for proto in http https
    do
        fetch_file "${proto}://{$dom}" && break
        for dir in "${dirs[@]}"
        do
            fetch_file "${proto}://${dom}/${dir}" && break 2
        done
    done
done > dir.result
```

If the domain list is massive, you could consider using `while read dom; do …; done < domain.list` instead of using the `$(cat domain.list)`. It would be feasible, and possibly even sensible, to define variable `site="${proto}://${dom}"` and then use that in the invocations of `fetch_file`.

Comment: Thanks too much for your help
i tested that and works very well , thanks again too much
but i have a little question 
i have tested the script for 1 domain , and about 10000 directory :D
at it takes more than an hour just to check the first 2 directory 

is that normal ???? should it take all that time ? 

thanks again for your help

Comment: The short answer is "I don't know".  A longer answer says: I would be surprised because normally a web-site will respond promptly to requests (sub-second usually, a very few seconds at most).  So, if there are performance problems, the first thing to do is add timing code to the function; print the URL and date before and after the `curl`, probably sending these outputs to standard error (`>&2`).  I wonder if the `https` connections are a cause of slowness?  You'll quickly find out with the timing in place.  Many sites respond the same to `http` and `https`, though by no means all do so.

Comment: the short answer from me is "i don't know " too :D
but when i tried to run new script with the https command only to check  10 directory , which i aimed to put working directory at the end of the list 
and i get the result in less than 3 minutes :)
that's very strange 
and iam not an expert , that's why i am sharing that info for you sir 
what do you think ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script:

```
while read dom; do
   while read dir; do
      target1="http://${dom}"
      target2="https://${dom}"
      target3="http://${dom}:${dir}"
      target4="https://${dom}:${dir}"

      if curl -s --insecure -m2 ${target1}/test.txt | grep -q "success"; then
         echo ${target1} >> dir.result
         break 2
      elif curl -s --insecure -m2 ${target2}/test.txt | grep -q "success"; then
         echo ${target2} >> dir.result
         break 2
      elif curl -s --insecure -m2 ${target3}/test.txt | grep -q "success"; then
         echo ${target3} >> dir.result
         break 2
      elif curl -s --insecure -m2 ${target4}/test.txt | grep -q "success"; then
         echo ${target4} >> dir.result
         break 2
      fi
   done < dir.list
done < domain.list
```